# Show that $(A+B)^{-1}\cdot A$ is a contraction

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that A and B are square positive definite matrices and I need to show that the map $(A+B)^{-1} A$ is a contraction. Of course if these were scalars it would be obvious. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

I've tried some examples numerically and haven't found a counter example so far.

Comment: Are we given that $(A + B)^{-1}A$ is positive definite, or is that something that you think is always true?

Comment: Weyl's inequalities may help here.

Comment: I understand that $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, but this in itself is not enough to guarantee that the matrix $(A + B)^{-1}A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Also, for you: does positive definite imply symmetric? (there are differing definitions in use).

Comment: I did read it.  You said "we are given they are" which made it sound like *you* thought that *I* mean "are $A$ and $B$ positive definite?".  I guess we're on the same page now.

Comment: I am sorry, I was mistaken. We don't have that $(A+B)^{-1}A$ is definite positive. I believe though the proof given by abel still works, right?

Comment: Abel's proof is only sufficient if we happen to know that the matrices involved here are symmetric and positive definite, which we don't. In particular, knowing the eigenvalues of $(A+B)^{-1}A$ isn't enough.

Comment: As a quick example, $\pmatrix{0.75&1\\0&0.75}$ is positive definite with eigenvalues between $0$ and $1$, but is not a contraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, do I have any hope of showing $(A+B)^{-1}A$ is a contraction, or at least give conditions for when that is the case, besides for when it is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Maybe you could show something when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. I don't really know when it's true

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ are positive definite in the conventional way, meaning they are symmetric, as you correctly pointed out, these do not imply that $(A+B)^{-1}A$ is positive definite or symmetric, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

i wonder if we can do this. suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $(A+B)^{-1}A.$ we will try to show that $0 < \lambda < 1.$

we have $$(A+B)^{-1}Ax = \lambda x \implies Ax = \lambda(A+B) x\implies(1-\lambda)Ax = \lambda Bx\implies (1-\lambda)x^\top Ax = \lambda x^\top Bx $$

now we can use the facts $x^\top Ax > 0, x^\top Bx > 0$ and $(1-\lambda)x^\top Ax = \lambda x^\top Bx$ to conclude that $0 < \lambda < 1$ which implies $(A+B)^{-1}A$ is a contraction.

Comment: Will this proof be generalized for non symmetric $(A+B)^{-1}A$ as follows?:

The idea is to take $M=(A+B)^{-1}A$, and characterize the eigenvalues of $MM^T$, to show that they are less than one, thus the singular values of $M$ are also less than one.

$(A+B)^{-1}AA(A+B)^{-1}x=\lambda x \implies (1-\lambda)(A+B)^{-1}AA(A+B)^{-1}x=\lambda(A+B)^{-1}[AB+BA+BB](A+B)^{-1}x \implies$

$$(1-\lambda)x^T(A+B)^{-1}AA(A+B)^{-1}x=\lambda x^T(A+B)^{-1}[AB+BA+BB](A+B)^{-1}x$$

Therefore the singular values which are the square root of the lambdas must also be less than one by a similar argument as Abel.